# Live handling does not work with event.stopPropagation();

Tags: jquery, live, stoppropagation

I'm using `event.stopPropagation()`, but I am having problems using `.live()` handler on the parent.

```
//does not work
$("#testlink").live({ 
    click: function(event) 
    { 
        alert('testlink'); 
    } 
}); 

//works great! 
$("#testlink").click(function() { 
  alert('testlink'); 
});
```

I have to use `.live()` because the content is loaded with AJAX.

Can someone help me with this problem?

---

How can i use more classes or ids like this?

```
$('#div1', '#div2', '#div3').on('click', 'a.testlink', function(){
   alert('testlink'); 
});
```

How is this possible?

Comment: `live()` is deprecated. Use `.on()` instead. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (as @techfoobar mentioned, [**live()**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated in version 1.7 and removed as of version 1.9) and event delegation if the content is dynamically generated:

```
$('#container').on('click', '#testlink', function(){
   alert('testlink'); 
});
```

Where `#container` is an element containing the dynamically loaded `#testLink` element (you could use `document`, but using a container element here reduces the search scope and increases efficiency).

Comment: Best solution is to use a `#container` element here. This will attach the event to any links within the `#container` element, reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

Comment: @PalashMondal Of course, but I don't know what the `#container` element is currently as OP hasn't provided enough detail (or any kind of markup) :)

Comment: At Least you can post that in your answer, as a suggestion :)

Comment: @PalashMondal Sure thing, wouldn't hurt. Updating now